# Sql Agent Jobs executes too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have posted a question like this before but is seems that I did not explain the whole story clear. So I made this one to explain it in details. Here's the stored procedure

```
USE [xxxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MARK_ACTIVE]    Script Date: 4/20/2015 5:55:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxx]
AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
INSERT INTO [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]      (smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX)
SELECT TOP 3 smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX
FROM [098.765.4.321].[[DBASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2] cr
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  id,smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX          FROM [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]  c
  WHERE cr.smsdt = c.smsdt)
```

and here's my job settings

**My General**
[image]

**My Steps**
[image]

**My advance steps**
[image]

**My Scheduler**
[image]

When I run the stored proc it executes for less than 10 seconds but when i try to call that stored proc using the job this is what happen

[image]

it just keep on in progress state but nothing happens, looks like it got stuck in that state.

Comment: it's better to ask this on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You are welcome, I'm sure that you'll get better answers at there for db administration related questions.

Comment: Open SQL Server Profiler. Start a new trace using the `TSQL_SPs` template. Now you can observe your stored procedure running in the database. Compare the Job version and the SSMS version. Can you confirm there is only ONE step in your job (you screenshotted everything except that window). Your stored procedure uses linked servers implying there could be user issues. Are you logging in as `sa` when you test it in SSMS?

Comment: Can you post a link to your stackdba question so we can remove this duplicate? Otherwise you have two sets of people working on the same question

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98385/sql-agent-jobs-executes-too-slow?noredirect=1#comment177478_98385